# InfluxDB Continuous Query: Keeping Tags

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to create a CQ and keep the tags.

My data looks like this; value is a float and then I have lot of tags.

```
select * from single_measurements order by time desc limit 10
name: single_measurements
time                     clientId machineId sensorGroupId sensorId typeId value
----                     -------- --------- ------------- -------- ------ -----
2019-02-01T22:19:03.155Z 8219     31        31            1003     1      -5728.96875
2019-02-01T22:19:03.155Z 8219     31        31            1002     1      5435.63525390625
2019-02-01T22:19:03.155Z 8219     31        31            1001     1      1859.4556884765625
2019-02-01T22:19:03.155Z 8219     31        31            1000     1      13231.85546875
2019-02-01T22:19:02.155Z 8219     31        31            1003     1      -5728.91943359375
2019-02-01T22:19:02.155Z 8219     31        31            1002     1      5435.68115234375
2019-02-01T22:19:02.155Z 8219     31        31            1001     1      1859.562744140625
2019-02-01T22:19:02.155Z 8219     31        31            1000     1      13232.0205078125
2019-02-01T22:19:01.155Z 8219     31        31            1003     1      -5728.92138671875
2019-02-01T22:19:01.155Z 8219     31        31            1002     1      5435.7177734375
```

1) I'm creating a policy:

```
create retention policy "a_year" on "mydb" duration 52w replication 1
```

2) Creating CQ

```
create continuous query "cq_15s" on "mydb" 
BEGIN SELECT mean(*) into "a_year"."downsampled_value" from "single_measurements" GROUP BY time(15s),* 
end
```

3) waiting 15s and run this query

```
select * from "a_year"."downsampled_value" limit 10
```

result is empty. I also realized that I can write wrong measurement-names and I don't get an error.

Btw.... this return me an non-empty result:

```
SELECT mean(*) FROM single_measurements GROUP BY time(15s),*
```

Environment:

```
Connected to http://localhost:8086 version 1.6.4
InfluxDB shell version: 1.6.4
```

show continuous queries:

```
name: _internal
name query
---- -----

name: ketag
name    query
----    -----
cq_15s  CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq_15s ON ketag BEGIN SELECT mean(*) INTO ketag.a_year.downsampled_value FROM ketag.autogen.single_measurements GROUP BY time(15s), * END
cq_15s2 CREATE CONTINUOUS QUERY cq_15s2 ON ketag BEGIN SELECT mean(*) INTO ketag.a_year.downsampled_value2 FROM ketag.autogen.single_measurements GROUP BY time(15s) END
```

Comment: Did you try using explicit full notation `<db>.<retention>.<measurement>` in `select` statements (fully qualify the destination measurement to store the downsampled data in a non-DEFAULT retention policy) to clarify the issue? Also run  `show` commands for measurements and continuous queries to see what is created.

Comment: @YuriLachin I have now added the SHOW command details

Comment: Looks like `SELECT * FROM ketag.a_year.downsampled_value` should work. If not  try running `SELECT mean(*) INTO ketag.a_year.downsampled_value FROM ketag.autogen.single_measurements GROUP BY time(15s), *` from CLI manually to see whether it works.